# Can not run npm using Laravel-mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, bourbon, laravel-mix

I am having some issue, its killing me. please help.
I am trying to run npm in DEV using command: npm run dev

In my webconfig.mix.js : `mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/style.scss', 'public/css');`

[image: This is errors that i got]

```
 95% emitting

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 4 errors                                                                                                                                                                                               05:33:52

This dependency was not found:

* -!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!../../../node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??postcss!bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.css in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":true,"ident":"postcss","plugins":[null]}!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"root":"/home/vagrant/Code/pudatalk/node_modules"}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sourceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/style.scss

To install it, you can run: npm install --save -!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!../../../node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??postcss!bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.css
```

Please see the error above.

So, i found out that its happening when i import :

```
@import "~bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/_bourbon.scss";
```

and i implemented something  like :

```
.error-bg-img {
    background:url("../img/errorbg.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
}
```

I am trying to tell you what i had in the code that occur the problem.

I have been trying google it, reinstall so many things, move things around but hopeless. I am a newbie in sass, webpack, and laravel-mix.

Thanks so much

Comment: Please post the text of your error, not a screenshot.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright guys,

I fixed the problem, i didn't now that webpack will automaticly copy the image in /img folder to /public. So i moved my /img from public/ folder to /resources/assests/. And everything is fine now.

Its all about the path. Sorry i am pretty new with webpack and didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
```

Have a look at the installation guideline  here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon#requirements

Comment: yeah. i follow their instruction. But i am not suing Gem to install it. I used npm. Not sure if thats right way.